# AndroidStudio kotlin AlertDialogue with spinner populated with setItems

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I want to show a modal dialogue for the user to select a Bluetooth device in the case that I can't guess it from the device names.

It appears that `AlertDialogue` has the facility to show a spinner / dropdown.

The alert dialogue builder has a method `setItems` which I seem to think is what I need, however, its parameter is `CharSequence[]` but I have some sort of array of strings (I can't tell exactly what I have because everything is just `val`).

```
    private fun showDialog() {
        val names = (bta!!.bondedDevices).map { z -> z.name }; 
        // What is the type of names? How can you find this out?
        // How can you make it into a CharSequence[]?

        val ab = AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ab.setTitle("Select device");
        ab.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert); // I'd prefer a question mark.
        ab.setPositiveButton("Select"){dialogueInterface, which -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()};
        ab.setNeutralButton("Cancel"){dialogueInterface, which -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()};

        ab.setItems(names); // None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
        val a = ab.create();
        a.setCancelable(false);
        a.show();
    }
```

I think this works in Java, but it doesn't in kotlin

```
CharSequence[] cs = list.toArray(new CharSequence[list.size()]);
```

So:

- In AndroidStudio how can you tell the type of a variable? (In VisualStudio if you hover over a `var` then the tooltip tells you.)
- How in kotlin do you make a `CharSequence[]`?

Comment: for converting the list to Array you can try `val cs: Array<CharSequence> = vowels_list.toTypedArray()`

Comment: to know the type of variable you can put the cursor on a variable or expression and press Ctrl+Shift+P or Cmd+Shift+P

Comment: Thank you, that answers that....

...and now on to the next problem that `setItems` requires a second parameter that is either a `listener: DialogInterface.OnClickListener!`. (What is the exclamation mark for?) Why do I need this? Don't I get the selected item as part of the dialogue result? What if the user clicks an item but then chooses cancel?

Answer (score 0):

```
    fun elmFind() {
        // Find device
        val pairedDevices: Set<BluetoothDevice>? = bta!!.bondedDevices

        // Try to guess.
        for (device in pairedDevices!!) {
            if (device.name.contains("obd")) {
                elmConnect(device.name);
                return;
            }
        }

        // Still going therefore didn't find one therefore ask.

        val cs: Array<CharSequence> = pairedDevices.map { z -> z.name }.toTypedArray()
        var elmDeviceName: String = ""

        val ab = AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ab.setTitle("Select device");
        ab.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
        ab.setPositiveButton("Select") { dialogueInterface, which ->
            elmConnect(elmDeviceName);
        };
        ab.setNeutralButton("Cancel") { dialogueInterface, which ->
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext,
                "Cancelled",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        };
        ab.setItems(cs) { dialog, which -> elmDeviceName = cs[which].toString() };
        val a = ab.create();
        a.setCancelable(false);
        a.show();
    }
```

Will this work with the local variable `elmDeviceName` being used to get the value of the selected item in the case when the OK button is pressed?